# SwiftUI how to keep track of page index in PageTabViewStyle?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I'm trying to keep track of what page the user is on in a `TabView` that is `PageTabViewStyle` in SwiftUI but I can't figure out the best way to keep track of the page index?  Using `.onAppear` doesn't work well as it gets called multiple times and pages 2 and 3 get called even when not on the screen.

```
@State var pageIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("current page = \(0) ")
        TabView {
            Text("First")
                .onAppear {
                    pageIndex = 0
                }
            Text("Second")
            .onAppear {
                    pageIndex = 1
                }
            Text("Third")
            .onAppear {
                    pageIndex = 2
                }
        }
         .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass a `selection` binding to the `TabView` and use `tag` to identify the pages:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var pageIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("current page = \(pageIndex) ")
            TabView(selection: $pageIndex) {
                Text("First").tag(0)
                Text("Second").tag(1)
                Text("Third").tag(2)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}
```

*Note that in your original code, it was always going to say current page = 0 because you weren't interpolating the `pageIndex` variable into the string*

Comment: I would recommend using enums just to make it look cleaner :)

Comment: @Rikh: you mean using enum in tag and instead of Integer, right?

Comment: Yep! Enum to keep track of current tab as well. Kinda like `@State private var current : Tabs`

Comment: Yes, that is certainly an option. Not sure how much 'cleaner' it looks since unfortunately the `tag()` doesn't do type inference based on the selection type. Maybe in a future version of SwiftUI. I went with Int because that's what the OP's question was set up as.

Comment: Wow this is great. I thought the tag was only a reference for the developer and I'd have to get and translate it into the `$pageIndex` somehow, but it already does that!

Comment: Make sure to **define the State value initially and don't leave it nil**, otherwise, it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be able to get the current page/index and act on that data, what I found useful is using the .onChange() modifier on the view, like so.

```
TabView(selection: $currentIndex) {
     Text("First view")
         .tag(0)
                
     Text("Middle view")
         .tag(1)
                
     Text("Last view")
         .tag(2)
}
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
.onChange(of: currentIndex) { newValue in
     print("New page: \(newValue)")
}
```

Hope that helps!